# Trying Validate a Binary Tree is Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am Learning Binary Search tree , and Trying this problem Binary tree is Binary search tree or Not?

by doing inorder traversing i want to check is it in ascending order or not ,

```
def isBst(self,root,prev = None):
        if root is not None:
            
            self.isBst(root.left,prev)
            if prev != None and root.data <= prev.data:
                return False
            prev = root
            self.isBst(root.right,prev)
        else:
            return True
```

here I am trying to store each inorder traverse in prev variable and checking the next traverse with the prev if it is less than that means it is not a BST ,else it will return True. that is what I want to do. but here I am trying like that, But I can't Understand What is Problem i am doing here? it's Giving None as an Output.

can any one please tell me and Help me to Understand this please?

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- The function can return `None`, because the `if` block does not end with a `return` statement, so the default `None` will be returned
- The main problem is that you do not use the return value from the recursive calls. Imagine that a recursive call returns False, which means there was a violation of the BST property somewhere... then your code just ignores that message and continues happily with the rest of the tree. So you should at least consider the return value -- something like this (but see next bullet point):

  ```
  valid = self.isBst(root.left, prev)
  if not valid:
      return False
  # ... other code...
  return True
  ```
- You seem to assume that the recursive call will modify the value of the caller's `prev` variable, but this is impossible. When you pass `prev` as argument, you do not pass the *variable*, but the value that that variable has, and the recursive execution context creates its own `prev` variable that starts out with that provided value. But any assignment to *that* variable is unrelated to the caller's `prev` variable.

Instead of trying to fix these issues, I would suggest a different approach, which I find also more intuitive to work with: create an in-order iterator in a separate function: a function that only deals with *yielding* one value after the other... nothing more. The actual `isBst` function can then just iterate over that iterator and easily detect a violation.

Here is how that would look:

```
class Solution:
    def traverse(self, root):
        if root:
            yield from self.traverse(root.left)
            yield root.data
            yield from self.traverse(root.right)

    def isBst(self, root):
        inorder = self.traverse(root)
        prev = next(inorder, None)  # smallest
        for value in inorder:  # the rest...
            if prev > value:
                return False
            prev = value
        return True
```

With `itertools.tee` you can make that `isBst` code a bit shorter:

```
    def isBst(self, root):
        import itertools
        # get two inorder iterators on the tree's values
        iprev, icurr = itertools.tee(self.traverse(root))
        # advance one of the two
        next(icurr, None)
        # check the pairs by consuming both iterators in tandem
        return all(prev <= curr for prev, curr in zip(iprev, icurr))
```